# Условие if в Selenium для прохождения теста

Tags: java

Есть Selenium + TestNG.

Тест: проверить открываемость (увеличенное изображение при наведении на фото) фотографии. Но бывает так, что фото без данной опции, из-за чего тест падает.

Вопрос: есть вариант поставить if(и как правильно), чтобы он проверял наличие зума? И если данный зум отсутствует, то скипать тест/шаг.

Пока попробовал `if(элемент.isDisplayed()) {Тест} else {}`. Но он все равно его ищет и не пропускает тест, если нету зума.

Comment: Точнее будет вопрос - как сделать проверку на наличие css элементов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забрать значение css аттрибутов делается с помощью метода [`getCssValue('value')`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/)

```
String value = component.getCssValue("cssValue");
//пример для background-color
String value = component.getCssValue("background-color");
```

На выходе будет `null`, если `cssValue` нет, иначе вернется строковое представление данного `css` аттрибута.

**Update**

Чтобы удостоверится, что элементов div.zoomPicture нет на странице, вы можете попытаться найти все такие элементы ( через `driver.findElements`) и если размер полученной коллекции 0, то элементов div.zoomPicture нет на странице.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но в данном случае мне не нужны характеристики элемента(хотя интересная вещь), а именно проверить в коде сайта страницы, есть он или нет.

Пример: есть на некоторых страницах div.zoomPicture, а на некоторых нет. Как проверить есть данный или нет? И вытекающий вследствие порос : если элемента нет, то как заскипать тест чтобы он не считался проваленным?

Comment: @sank смотри апдейт ответа

Comment: Спасибо, работает.  

List<WebElement> listOfZoomPicture =  
 driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.zoomLens"));  
  if (listOfZoomPicture.size() > 0) {  
Текст теста  
} else {System.out.println("Нет зума на фотографии");}